# Please Identify a Cartoon about a Rebel Hero in a Water War

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

Kindly tell me the name of this cartoon.

In it, the Earth is broken into pieces and there is a water war. At the beginning, the main character is the son of a woman who has telekinesis. The hero finds a jet which is used by his father. He starts a rebel group. I remember that the villains have an S-like symbol on their ships, like in the picture below.

I shall be grateful if anyone can tell me the name of that cartoon.

[image: S-like symbol]

Comment: Roughly when did it come out and what language was it in? Do you remember a channel?

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/230791/animated-series-where-people-live-in-the-sky (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that that sounds like Skyland, see the wiki. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skyland)

Skyland (full French title: "Skyland, Le Nouveau Monde", or "Skyland, The New World"), is a CGI animated series developed in France in partnership with Canada and Luxembourg for television channels France 2, Teletoon, Nicktoons, ABC and CITV

...

Prior to the beginning of the story, the Earth has shattered into billions of pieces which orbit around a central core. In this new world, named Skyland, an evolved form of human has appeared: Seijins, who absorb energy from sunlight and use it to fuel special abilities such as telekinesis, telepathy, mental control, astral projection, energy balls or blasts, and electric rays.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for the Japanese-sounding name "Seijin"?